# How to load entire file in REPL as with paste

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Scala REPL has useful function `:Load` that allows to import entire file to the current session. But it gives me warning:

> warning: previously defined object Holder is not a companion to trait Holder.
>
> Companions must be defined together; you may wish to use :paste mode for this.

How can I load entire file preserving companion relation between classes and objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just say `:paste myfile`.

It's been supported awhile.

https://github.com/scala/scala/blame/2.11.x/src/repl/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/ILoop.scala#L697

Answer (score 1):

Did you try paste mode?

```
scala> :paste myfile.sc
```

Or the abbreviated

```
scala> :pa myfile.sc
```